# Box Spout format cell type to Number

Tags: format, cell, box, spout

Is it possible to change cell type to Number in Box Spout? For the moment when I export an excel file all cells type are General .

Thanks,
Florida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to specify the cell type at the moment.

But if you use numbers (12.34) and not strings ("12.34"), Excel is able to process the value as a number.